# Ruby rack middleware to filter all the exceptions raised in the stack

Tags: ruby, exception, rack, middleware

Hi I just had a question on how to appropriately manage exception handling with ruby rack.

I am currently building a lightweight API with Sinatra/Rack and every route could through an exception (e.g. Missing Parameter, Invalid Format etc). I want to be able to catch all of these exceptions and handle them in a middleware application. I don't want to catch or 'rescue' within each get, post, put, delete block (e.g. post '/me')

I tried something like this, where ExceptionHandler is at the top of the rack stack.

i am missing something?

```
class Api::ExceptionHandler

  def initialize(application)
    @application = application
  end

  def call(environment)
    @application.call environment
  rescue Api::MissingParameterError => parameter
    [ 400, { }, [ "parameter #{parameter} missing" ] ]
  end

end
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap the call statemen in a begin/rescue blog. Also, some possible Exceptions might be found here: http://adventuresincoding.com/2010/09/writing-modular-http-client-code-with-faraday/ (although that's the client-side view)

Comment: This code, as written, will catch MissingParameterError exceptions as intended.  Can you provide a more complete rackup file to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, As Catnapper said, the code above should work! What I didn't mention was that all my middleware is inheriting a class that inherits Sinatra::Base.

And Sinatra has its own exception handlers, which can be modified like this

```
set :raise_errors, false
set :show_exceptions, false
```

And this is how you write an exception handler in sinatra (for the example in the question):

```
error Api::MissingParameterError do |parameter|
  status 400
  headers { }
  body "parameter #{parameter} missing"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Sinatra 1.4 version (used by Padrino since version 0.11) there are changes in error http status definition. Here is a part from `sinatra-1.4.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb` related to "handle_exception!" function

```
 if boom.respond_to? :http_status 
   status(boom.http_status)
 elsif settings.use_code? and boom.respond_to? :code and boom.code.between? 400, 599  
   status(boom.code)
 else
   status(500)
 end
```

So if your exception class has "http_status" method then error status defined from it. Only server errors (the ones with codes since 500 to 599) can reach middleware depending on "raise_errors" and "show_exceptions" settings due to this (the same "handle_exception!" function a bit below):

```
  return res if res or not server_error?
  raise boom if settings.raise_errors? or settings.show_exceptions?
```

Good news, default error status is 500. So if you do need your exception to propagate middleware just **prevent your exception class from responding to "http_status" method** or use http_status codes since 500 to 599. But for the example in the question best way is to use `error` method like Max described.